# Plugins do not appear after installing yui plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have just tried to install the YUI plugin (in order to install the [Grails UI plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/grails-ui), which requires the YUI Plugin and the Bubbling Plugin), but now I'm completely stuck on what it has done to my Eclipse. After installing it, I tried to run the refresh-dependencies command and get this error:

Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/yui/%5B2.6.0,)/yui-%5B2.6.0,).pom

```
Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/yui/maven-metadata.xml

Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/yui/%5B2.6.0,)/yui-%5B2.6.0,).zip
```

| Error Error executing script RefreshDependencies: Cannot find plugin descriptor in plugin directory '\storage.adsroot.itcs.umich.edu\home\windat.V2.grails\2.1.0\projects\HardwareProject4\plugins\yui-minify-resources-0.1.4'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Also, the plugins directory in Eclipse is suddenly EMPTY even though I had confirmation that the Grails UI, YUI Plugin, and Bubbling Plugin had been installed (I had also had a the Plugin Platform UI and a custom plugin installed beforehand as well). So now I cannot even uninstall any of the plugins if I needed to.

Has anyone run into this problem before? Any ideas on how to resolve this? Any help would be much appreciated....thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you installed them? Are you using `builConfig.groovy`?